# PHPMyAdmin not showing foreign-key related data in search or insert

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Sometimes it happens so, that PHPMYadmin isn't displaying names (or at least some data) from foreign keys in Insert/Search pages. It seems to be just empty.

Our used version is 5.1.3

Can you please recommend on how to fix this?

[image]